# Handgun modeling tips

Tags: modeling

[image]

My main question is with the grip and safety, specifically the bumps (peep https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1911_pistol#/media/File:M1911A1.png). I am not familiar with the texturing process, and i've heard things about "baking" normalmaps out of a high-poly model to fake high-detail areas, so should I model all of the little bumps, bake the normals, and then retopologize or is there another way I can do it? I am planning on animating and texturing the model and eventually importing it to ue4 at some point, so is there anything I need to do to accommodate that? Thanks for any help yall can offer.

Comment: (1) Nice job on the gun model, (2) it is completely up to you as to whether or not to bake a normal map from a high poly model or just to paint a displacement map directly, (3) this question is very broad and is much better suited to a site like [blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/forum/).

Comment: Also there is really no way out of modelling, you need it both for final mesh or as intermediary step for baking. Weather or not to bake is really up to the final use for your model, if it is for a game engine, then I am guessing polygon counts are gonna be an issue, so baking may be advised.